# Detect click event on UIButton placed on camera overlay view

Tags: iphone, overlay

I have an overlay view placed on camera view controller. The overlay view has a button on it. How to detect click event on the button and display a new modal view controller on that button click...
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the button's target to a selector as you would do with any other button.